# Best Way to Implement an Edge Weighted Graph in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

First of all, I'm dealing with graphs more than 1000 edges and I'm traversing adjacency lists, as well as vertices more than 100 times per second. Therefore, I really need an efficient implementation that fits my goals.

My vertices are integers and my edges are undirected, weighted.

I've seen [this](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/43mst/EdgeWeightedGraph.java.html) code.
However, it models the adjacency lists using edge objects. Which means I have to spend `O(|adj|)` of time when I'd like to get the adjacents of a vertex, where `|adj|` is the cardinality of its adjacents.

On the other hand, I'm considering to model my adjacency lists using `Map<Integer, Double>[] adj`.
By using this method, I would just use `adj[v]`, `v` being the vertex, and get the adjacents of the vertex to iterate over.

The other method requires something like:

```
public Set<Integer> adj(int v) 
{
    Set<Integer> adjacents = new HashSet<>();
    for(Edge e: adj[v])
        adjacents.add(e.other(v));
    return adjacents;
}
```

My goals are:

- I want to sort a subset of vertices by their connectivities (number of adjacents) any time I want.
- Also, I need to sort the adjacents of a vertex, by the weights of the edges that connect itself and its neighbors.
- I want to do these without using so much space that slows down the operations. Should I consider using an adjacency matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used th JGrapht for a library for a variety of my own graph representations.  They have a weighted graph implementation here: http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/graph/SimpleWeightedGraph.html

That seems to handle a lot of what you are looking for, and I've used it to represent graphs with up to around 2000 vertices, and it handles reasonably well for my needs, though I don't remember my access rate.

Comment: Is there a way to define custom edges in JGraphT?

Comment: The constructor for the weighted graph takes an edge class or an edge factory as an argument.  I don't see why you can't have your custom class extend those to use them as an argument